# Question asking... Difficulty in understanding the return statement

Tags: python-3.x

I am having difficulty in understanding the return statement in python. Can anyone give me a code or an example to let me understand..

Comment: What kind of experience do you have in programming? In other languages? Did you read the tutorial? https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/

Comment: i am new to python . and i have been learning it since 2 weeks. please help me if you can. i would appreciate that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the purpose of the return statement? How is it different from printing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129285/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-return-statement-how-is-it-different-from-printing)

Answer (score 1):

A return statement is used at the end of the function and "returns" the result of the function to the caller.
For example:

```
def minus (x,y):
   return x - y

result = minus(2,1)

print("Result: ", result)
```

> > Result: 1

**NOTE : Codes after the return statement are not executed.**